# Validating against a Schema with JAXB

Tags: xml, validation, schema, jaxb, well-formed

I've been looking for solutions to this problem for far too long considering how easy it sounds so I've come for some help.

I have an XML Schema which I have used with xjc to create my JAXB binding.  This works fine when the XML is well formed.  Unfortunately it also doesn't complain when the XML is not well formed.  I cannot figure out how to do proper full validation against the schema when I try to unmarshall an XML file.

I have managed to use a ValidationEventCollector to handle events, which works for XML parsing errors such as mismatched tags but doesn't raise any events when there is a tag that is required but is completely absent.

From what I have seen validation can be done againsta  schema, but you must know the path to the schema in order to pass it into the setSchema() method.  The problem I have is that the path to the schema is stored in the XML header and I can't knwo at run time where the schema is going to be.  Which is why it's stored in the XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<DDSSettings xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="/a/big/long/path/to/a/schema/file/DDSSettings.xsd">
<Field1>1</Field1>
<Field2>-1</Field2>
```

...etc

Every example I see uses setValidating(true), which is now deprecated, so throws an exception.

This is the Java code I have so far, which seems to only do XML validation, not schema validation:

```
try {
    JAXBContext jc = new JAXBContext() {
        private final JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance("blah");

        @Override
        public Unmarshaller createUnmarshaller() throws JAXBException {
            Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
            ValidationEventCollector vec = new ValidationEventCollector() {
                @Override
                public boolean handleEvent(ValidationEvent event) throws RuntimeException {
                    ValidationEventLocator vel = event.getLocator();
                    if (event.getSeverity() == event.ERROR || event.getSeverity() == event.FATAL_ERROR) {
                        String error = "XML Validation Exception:  " + event.getMessage() + " at row: " + vel.getLineNumber() + " column: " + vel.getColumnNumber();
                        System.out.println(error);
                    }
                    m_unmarshallingOk = false;
                    return false;
                }
            };
            unmarshaller.setEventHandler(vec);

            return unmarshaller;
        }

        @Override
        public Marshaller createMarshaller() throws JAXBException {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
        }

        @Override
        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        public Validator createValidator() throws JAXBException {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
        }
    };

    Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
    m_ddsSettings = (com.ultra.DDSSettings)unmarshaller.unmarshal(new File(xmlfileName));
} catch (UnmarshalException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(UniversalDomainParticipant.class.getName()).log(
    Level.SEVERE,
    null, ex);
} catch (JAXBException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(UniversalDomainParticipant.class.getName()).log(
    Level.SEVERE,
    null, ex);
}
```

So what is the proper way to do this validation?  I was expecting there to be a validate() method on the JAXB generated classes, but I guess that would be too simple for Java.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

OK, I've found the solution.  Using the schema factory to create a schema, but without specifying a schema file makes it work with the noNamespaceSchemaLocation specified in the XML file.

So the code from above has had this added:

```
SchemaFactory factory = SchemaFactory.newInstance("http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema");
Schema schema = factory.newSchema();
Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
unmarshaller.setSchema(schema);
m_ddsSettings = (com.ultra.DDSSettings)unmarshaller.unmarshal(new File(xmlfileName));
```

Shame that took the best part of 24 hours to find the answer to!

The javadoc for [`SchemaFactory.newSchema()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/validation/SchemaFactory.html#newSchema%28%29) says:

> For XML Schema, this method creates a
>   Schema object that performs validation
>   by using location hints specified in
>   documents.
>
> The returned Schema object assumes
>   that if documents refer to the same
>   URL in the schema location hints, they
>   will always resolve to the same schema
>   document. This asusmption allows
>   implementations to reuse parsed
>   results of schema documents so that
>   multiple validations against the same
>   schema will run faster.

Comment: Interesting, I didn't know that. I took the liberty of adding some info to your answer, for future reference.

Comment: Instead of specifying the XMLSchema URL explicitly, per the javadocs, use the appropriate value from XMLConstants as specified here:  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/index.html?javax/xml/validation/Schema.html

Comment: @icfantv our are right, I use: Schema schema = SchemaFactory.newInstance (XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI).newSchema (); // but the reference was: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/index.html?javax/xml/validation/Schema.html - Additionally the thing i didn't understand about this solution is that the url is constant: it does not refer to the location of our own schema (was not obvious to me)

Comment: oops: direct reference to XMLConstants: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/XMLConstants.html#W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, you just have to set the schema with [Marshaller.setSchema()](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/Marshaller.html#setSchema(javax.xml.validation.Schema)) to a schema created by the [SchemaFactory](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/validation/SchemaFactory.html) from your `DDSSettings.xsd`. This will turn validation on.

Comment: But the problem is that I don't know the path to that XSD file at compile time and am not given it at run time- it's stored in the XML file heading only.

Comment: But if you have jaxb-classes, they should have been generated from a schema. Why not include the schema in your project?

Comment: JAXB doesn't *have* to work with a schema and generated code, it works perfectly well without a schema.