# JAXB: Unmarshall invalid xml document to object

Tags: java, jaxb, unmarshalling

I have the following class that I am going to use for unmarshalling appropriate XML document:

```
 @XmlRootElement(name = "address")
 public class AddressObject {

        @XmlElement(name = "domain")
        public String domain = new String();
        @XmlElement(name = "ip-address")
        public String ipAddress = new String();
        @XmlElement(name = "user-agent")
        public String userAgent = new String();
    }
```

In order to unmarshall document, I use `javax.xml.bind.Unmarshaller`. Using code below:

```
JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(AddressObject.class);
Unmarshaller unmarshaller = context.createUnmarshaller();
StreamSource streamSource = new StreamSource(new StringReader(SOME_CORRECT_XML_DOC));
JAXBElement<AddressObject> obj = unmarshaller.unmarshal(streamSource, AddressObject.class);
```

It works fine as long as incorrect xml uses, like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?><hello-world></hello-world>
```

In the last case xml **unmarshall without any errors.**

Can someone explain why it's happening? I have expected to recieve any errors regarding invalid tags or something like this.

Comment: I think that's because by default JAXB treats public fields and properties as mapped.  If you annotate a field it then considers the field and property as mapped causing the conflict.  Without `@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)` you should annotate the get or set method.

**For More Information**

  - http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/06/using-jaxbs-xmlaccessortype-to.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, JAXB does not validate on its own. You have to specify the schema if you want to turn on the validation:

[Validating against a Schema with JAXB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2491859/validating-against-a-schema-with-jaxb)

JAXB is not strict on mappings. It takes what it can map according to the annotations and ignores the rest. Also the order of elements is not significant on unmarshalling.

I was a long term JAXB 1.x user. JAXB 1.x was very strict. I am extremely glad that JAXB 2 is not so strict.

Next, if you use

```
unmarshaller.unmarshal(streamSource, AddressObject.class);
```

you basically ignore the root element mapping as you specify the target class explicitly. That is, your `hello-world` is accepted as the root element despite it does not match the `address` in your `AddressObject`.

So all of this is valid and expected behavior.